# Как вставить в HTML блок стиль полученный из JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
// установливаем обработчик события resize
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $("header").text($(window).height());
    });

// вызовем событие resize
    $(window).resize();
```

В блок с классом .header вставляется текст с размером текущей высоты браузера, а мне надо, что бы эти цифры в стили шли:

```
    <header class="header" style="height: 1240px">
       Тут моя верстка
    </header>
```

Заранее всех благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("header").css("height", $(window).height());
});
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @alex-lenk, тьфу, да, там не двоеточие, а запятая. Исправил ответ.

Comment: То что доктор прописал, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 2):

Ответ Станислава верный. Но я просто оставлю это здесь.

Если вам требуется уставновить значение чего-либо в пропорции к окну, вы можете обойтись без js. Я говорю про так называемые [`viewport units`](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/) для современных браузеров.

Поэтому, альтернативный путь решения вашего вопроса - установить `100vh` к высоте хедера в css стилях:

```
header {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Посмотреть [поддержку браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: забыл про это свойство, и как раз поддержка браузеров мне подходит, спасибо большое. Воспользовался вашим ответом!

Comment: @alex-lenk слева зеленое спасибо ;)

Comment: Хотел поставить, но не имею права, вопрос про скрипт задавал, человек ответил, помог мне. А вы дали альтернативный способ, который я и применил.